# xpath to get lists of element in Python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape lists of elements from a page that looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <b>1</b>
    <b>2</b>
    <b>3</b>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <b>4</b>
    <b>5</b>
    <b>6</b>
</div>
```

I would like to get lists or tuples using xpath: [1,2,3],[4,5,6]...

Using for loop on the page I get either the first element of each list or all numbers as one list.

Could you please help me to solve the exercise?
Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: have you tried using beautifulsoup?

Comment: no, not yet. if there is no chance to achieve the goal using xpath, then i will try to find out with beautifulsoup

Comment: well it will be quite easy with bs4.

Comment: @ValeryD. , BeautifulSoup doesn't support XPath. You can try [lxml.html](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) instead

Comment: Thanks, Andersson! Yes, I've found out already with Gahan's help. I have nothing against bs4, except that i've never been using it. Nevertheless, it appears not that complicated and it works as desired (i've got the desired results already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For web-scraping of static pages [bs4](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/) is best package to work with. and using [bs4](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/)  you can achieve your goal as easy as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source = """<div class="container">
    <b>1</b>
    <b>2</b>
    <b>3</b>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <b>4</b>
    <b>5</b>
    <b>6</b>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')  # parse content/ page source
soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'container'})  # find all the div element (second argument is optional mentioned to scrape/find only element with attribute value)
print([[int(x.text) for x in i.find_all('b')] for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'container'})])  # get list of all div's number list as you require
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Gahan!

Answer (score 0):

you could use this xpath expression, which will give you two strings

```
.//*[@class='container']    ➡ '1 2 3', '4 5 6'
```

if you would prefer 6 strings

```
.//*[@class='container']/b  ➡ '1','2','3','4','5','6'
```

to get exactly what you are looking for though you would have to separate the xpath expressions

```
.//*[@class='container'][1]/b  ➡ '1','2','3'
.//*[@class='container'][2]/b  ➡ '4','5','6'
```